# django date filter %z (day of the year) with 3 digits

Tags: django, date, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm working on a django template, and I want to format a date with the following format 'YYDDD' (sometimes known as julian date format) where:

- YY is the last 2 digits of the year
- DDD is the day of the year with 3 digit format

I tried to achive this with the date filter:

```
{{ value|date:"yz" }}
```

but "z" doesn't keep the output with 3 digits, it uses the minimum possible amount. If the day number is 3 (3rd January) it will print 3 istead 003.

For example, for the date *7th February of 2012* i would expect **12038** but instead I get **1238** (no zero padding).

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your [django custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) or use [jcroft's snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/543/):

```
{{ value|date:"y" }}{{ value|date:"z"|leading_zeros:"3" }}
```

Comment: Perfect! That was the orientation I was looking for. I end up writing my own filter based on jcroft's snippet.
Thanks.